# C++ std::string how to format String literal with multiple double quotes?

Tags: c++, stdstring

I have a std::string literal with double quotes inside double quotes, inside double quotes.
What format do I need to use to make it work?
Here is an example:

```
std:string http_command = "wget --post-data="user=bla password=bla query=select * from bla bla where username="" and name=bla\" http:://example.com"
```

The following part is failing `username=""`

Thanks guys.

Update: Fixed my sample, I had one extra double quote there.

Comment: In post-data, shouldn't you have quotes around the query ?

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string http_command = "wget --post-data=\"user=bla password=bla query=\"select * from bla bla where username=\"\" and name=bla\" http:://example.com"
```

Escape all quotes other than the first and last (the ones delimiting your string).

Comment: Do the internal backslashes need escaping?

Comment: Yes, some of this text is already escaped, so the escapes also need escaping.  (I'm looking forward to MS finally implementing R"" in my compiler)

Comment: @PeterWood yes, but as far as I can tell, there aren't any (other than the ones escaping the quotes.)

Comment: @PeterWood Just saw your comment, and I had the same feeling. Did you mean what I have put in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
std:string http_command = "wget --post-data=\"user=bla password=bla query=\\\"select * from bla bla where username=\\\\\\"\\\\\\" and name=bla\\\" \" http:://example.com"
```

A bit of a guess, but I think that you have to escape the internal backslahes.
Note that I think you were missing a quote at the end of the post data.

Comment: You're right I had an extra double quote, i fixed it. Unfortunately your solution didn't work either.

Comment: what is the error message ? also I am surprised that the SQL strings are delimited by double quotes and not single quotes.

Comment: There is no error. I'm hitting a custom database and filtering the results. One of my filters is a field whose value is empty double quotes. When I run using your example above, the database returns no results. I've tried running this directly via terminal and I get the results back. However, in a terminal I only double quotes inside double quotes.